# Git clone erroring inside chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a git repo which i want to download locally when chef-client runs.
So i create the following recipe

https://gist.github.com/houami/b70f49525002b51dd1fe03cce357a883

When kitchen converge happens,chef-client errors out saying

https://gist.github.com/houami/31b8002ffb5870075c4310cd5c6a90fd

Answer (score 1):

That isn't an error from Chef, it's a problem downloading your cookbooks with Berkshelf. Make sure that `berks install` is working. You can also look at the `kitchen.log` file to find the full stack trace to narrow down the problem. Looks like you accidentally dumped a whole project repo into your cookbook.